# Windows service status

Tags: c#-4.0

I have written a windows service in C#.net and installed it successfully. When I run the service manually, it runs but the status of the service doesnt change to stopped. How can I make it to change its staus to stopped once the operation is over.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well the service normally registers itself with the SCM, and reports it's status to the SCM. Although if the service isn't running at all the SCM will simply mark it as stopped.

I would suggest reading Microsoft's introduction to services to get a better idea of how they work, and the best practices to use.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx

Comment: Thanks Zipper. Its a good article.

I did it using this.stop() once the operation is over. And I am getting the proper status in the parent code that is calling the service.

Thanks